# Issue with MVC5 entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC5, Entity Framework 6 in Visual Studio 2013 in my web application. I am trying my model to work but getting error for one reason another. I have tried both Fluent API and just model on its own. I am sure it must be something silly but I am stuck.. need help. Currently I am getting error in mapping and modeling classes .. i have add the controller in which when i debug for var=a1 i get following error

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Test Model class

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int testID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Class

```
public class TestMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestMap>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.testID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("testTable");
        this.Property(t => t.testID).HasColumnName("testID");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
    }
}
```

Context

```
public class My_Context : DbContext
{
    public My_Context()
        : base("name=My_Context")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         Database.SetInitializer<DORIS_Context>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DORIS_Context>());
        //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestMap());    
    }

    public DbSet<TestModel> Test { get; set; }
}
```

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="My_Context"
</connectionStrings>
```

### controller

```
 public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var db = new DORIS_Context())
        {
            var query = from b in db.Test
                        orderby b.testID
                        select b;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                var a1 = item.Title;
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: test map is commented out and would be required since the model doesnt meet standard conventions.  The error effectively says. `Model is Broken`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason you initialized the `DORIS_Context` class in your `My_Context` class? Your `DbSet<TestModel>` is defined in `My_Context` class, but in your action method, you're using `DORIS_Context` to call it.

If it's not necessary, comment out below line

```
// Database.SetInitializer<DORIS_Context>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DORIS_Context>());
```

Then, change `EntityTypeConfiguration<TestMap>` to below:

```
public class TestMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestModel>
```

and your Index action should looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new My_Context())
    {
       //
    }
    return View();
}
```

Also you probably need to add keyattribute in TestModel like below:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public int testID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```