# Why am I getting System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

Please be kind, I am a newbie to c#.

I get this exception on my `controller`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Tickets.ToList());
}
```

This is what my `model` looks like:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int ticketID { get; set; }
    public string ticketTitle { get; set; }     
}
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is db in the above code?

Comment: private BugTrackerContext db = new BugTrackerContext();

Comment: It might help, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541056/issue-with-mvc5-entity-framework

Comment: As a best practice, put your BugTrackerContext in an using statement.

Comment: Check the inner exception.  Does it give any more information?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777004/modelvalidationexception-was-unhandled-user-code

Comment: Thanks guys, Vimalan that helped me a lot. Turned out I had declared an incorrect type for the id field on a separate model

Answer (score 0):

I changed my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            return View(db.Tickets.ToList());
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException ex)
        {

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }

    }
```

Turns out I had declared  ticketID as foreign key with a wrong type on a separate model. I hope this helps someone.